# Update sharepoint 2013 custom list's field "Modified" C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

How to update the "modified" field in sharepoint 2013 using Document Object Library C#. Currently i'm using the following code, but every time i run this code, "modified" field is always updated with current DateTime.

```
       SP.ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

       SP.ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

       String LastModifiedDate = "12/14/2014 7:01:09 PM";

       oListItem["Modified"] = Convert.ToDateTime(LastModifiedDate);

       oListItem.Update();

       clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: if you are using the SharePoint CSOM (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client) then you do not have access to `SystemUpdate` -- see here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29362/client-object-model-systemupdate

Answer (score 2):

If you change your `Update` call to a `SystemUpdate` call; that should do the trick.

```
oListItem.SystemUpdate();
```

Comment: oListItem doesn't contain a function named SystemUpdate().
Its not working !

Comment: Please see this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate.aspx  what Library are you using?

Comment: I'm using CSOM. with SharePoint 2013

Comment: I'd recommend creating some server side handler or service if you need to perform that sort of operation and call that services from your client-side code and pass it json formatted data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SystemUpdate() instead of Update(). But as Glenn said this is a server side function and it is not supported by CSOM. If you want you can write a webservice which updated the list metadata one by one and in that way modified date will not be updated.